# How to access dynamic generated HTML from a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, plugins, dynamic, xul

I want to access dynamic generated HTML code from my FF extension (XUL).

for example, I have created a toolbar button using XUL, then when I click on this toolbar button I need a javascript code to be done to access the DOM objects of a certain page/url.

But unfortunately this page generates its code dynamically, so element.innerHTML always returns an empty string.

Can anyone please help, this is urgent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes but I need a solution. what shall I do :)